# What are some good resources for 相声 and 小品?

Tags: resources

These two seem to involve lots of colloquial Chinese and I want to know where I can learn it.  I want to focus on the Beijing/Tianjin dialect.

Comment: Just a heads up that questions asking for learning resources are generally off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can get these on Youtube by searching the actor/actress's name.

For instance, search "赵丽蓉" "巩汉林" will give you a lot of good 小品, and search for "马三立" for 相声 with Tianjin dialect. If you want 相声 with Beijing dialect, you can search "郭德纲".